# Why is this entity not saving? [BreezeJS/AngularJS]

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, breeze

So I'm currently working on a project that uses Entity Framework, Breeze and Angular and now i'm stuck. I retrieve a single Entity, change a property and then try to save that. But even though the EntityState indicates that it's been modified it does not save.

So I guess for some reason it has lost it's binding to Breeze or something. The change that I make is reflected on the page however so I suppose Angular still 'sees' it.

Here is the relevant code from my controller:

```
trService.getProposalById($route.current.params.Id)
    .then(function (query) {
        $scope.proposal = query.results[0];
        trService.getTrById($scope.proposal.TrID)
        .then(function (query) {
            $scope.itinerary = query.results[0];
        })
        .then(function (query) {
            //Something irrelevant
        });
    });
```

Checking the $scope.proposal after this shows that it's an Entity (ctor.proto thing). Then my function for when i'm approving/saving:

```
$scope.onApproveConfirm = function () {

        console.log("Before: " + $scope.proposal.entityAspect.entityState.name);
        $scope.proposal.IsApproved = 2;
        console.log("After: " + $scope.proposal.entityAspect.entityState.name);

        trService.saveChanges($scope.proposal, undefined, function (result) {
            console.log("Saved: " + result.entities.length);
        }, function () {
            console.log("Save failed");
        });
    };
```

Output in the console looks like this:

```
Before: Unchanged
After: Modified
Saved: 0
```

I use the saveChanges for all my other Entities without any problems. In the code between where I retrieve the proposal and where I change the IsApproved property I never access it. So can anyone see from this what goes wrong? If you need any additional info im happy to supply it.

Also if I put the save code directly after retrieving the proposal it does save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that you didn't get an error in your `saveChanges` call because you're passing in an object (an entity) rather than an array of entities [as the API requires](http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_saveChanges). Breeze should have given you an error immediately. I show you how I think you should have called it down below.

Stylistically, I'd like to suggest that you use promises rather than pass callbacks to the method. The callbacks signature is a backward compatibility thing and should really be deprecated.

Do you really need to specify the entity to save? This is called "cherry picking the save". It's great when you need it but I try to avoid it because it can lead to subtle bugs when you forget to save a changed entity that should be (perhaps must be) part of the save transaction. However, I'll pretend that you *really do* want to save this particular entity apart from all other potentially unsaved pending changes.

Putting these thoughts together, I think it should look more like this:

```
trService.saveChanges([$scope.proposal]) // <--- note the array
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log("Saved: " + result.entities.length);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Save failed: " + error.message);
    });
```

One final question. Is your service working for you? It seems to be exposing the internals of the way you interact with Breeze. The usual reason for *having a data service* like this is to encapsulate interactions with Breeze so that the consumer (e.g., a controller/ViewModel) can obtain persistence services w/o bogging down in implementation concerns. That's a highly recommended practice. But exposing your `EntityManager` operations through the `trService` interface is just a fig leaf don't you think.

Or maybe I'm worrying for nothing ... and what we're seeing here is just you trying to reveal the problem so we can help ... in which case, ignore this last critical comment.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. What I maybe should have mentioned is that this is a project i'm just continuing and the saveChanges() mentioned here does some extra stuff before calling Breeze's saveChanges.

The reason I am 'cherrypicking' is that I'm at the same time editing an other Entity which should not be saved yet. And yes, the service is working.

I actually decided to choose an other path for this in the end.

Comment: Then all is well? I'm relieved. Happy coding!